# Changing "NULL" string in an array to undef in the array perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I am building an array from a datafile that is used as a parameter list to a cached SQL statement.  This is for perl DBI running against an Oracle database.

For example:

```
@params = ("This", "that", "NULL", "finish");
```

I need this changed to:

```
@params = ("This", "that", undef, "finish");
```

I have googled for this and map with s/// is suggested for string substition.  I do not know how to undef an element in an array for a given condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for (@params) { $_ = undef if $_ eq 'NULL'; }
```

Comment: is there a benefit to using for rather than map here?

Comment: @nickisfat : `map` should be used to transform one list to another. Here, no new list is being transformed, so `for` is a better construct. If you really wanted to use `map`, `@params = map { $_ eq 'NULL' ? undef : $_ } @params;` is one way to do it, albeit with unnecessary complication.

Comment: @nickisfat, You mean `@params = map { $_ eq 'NULL' ? undef : $_ } @params;`? That would probably involve a lot of needless copying. Why not change the array directly? If we were taking a list and placing it into a fresh array, I'd use `map`.

Answer (score 5):

`@params = map { $_ eq 'NULL' ? undef : $_ } ("This", "that", "NULL", "finish");` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done very simply using a `for` loop over a list provided by `grep`:

```
undef $_ for grep $_ eq 'NULL', @params;
```

Comment: I'd use `$_ = undef;` over `undef $_;`. The former sets the var to undefined. The second frees memory that wouldn't otherwise be freed for performance reasons.